# Pyramid - Is it possible to render my mako template as a string within my view callable?

Tags: python, ajax, json, pyramid

I have a view callable that does looks similar to:

```
def post_comment(request):
    """ Posts the users comment to the thread """

    try:
        new_comment = comments.post()
    except InvalidComment as e:
        return {'success' : False, 'message' : e.message}

    # need to do something like:
    new_comment = pyramid.template.render(new_comment)

    return {'success' : True, 'message' : new_comment}
```

The route config for this view callable is:

```
config.add_route('post_comment',
                 '/comments/{link_id}/post',
                 view='site.views.post_comment',
                 view_renderer='json')
```

Using this, I can AJAXify my comment submissions and have a shiny web 2.0 website. The problem is, I'd like to render `new_comment` through my mako template to build the HTML and return that. However, I can't find a way to do this.

How can I render a mako template within my view callable to return the HTML as a JSON response?

Answer (score 8):

You can call `render` directly using the documented Pyramid API here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/api/renderers.html#pyramid.renderers.render

```
from pyramid.renderers import render

def my_view(request)
    renderer_dict = {} # dictionary of values to pass to the renderer
    new_comment = render('new_comment.mako', renderer_dict, request)
    …
```

Comment: how to import render? please post the import line.

Comment: Like the documentation says, it's in the `pyramid.renderers` module. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/renderers.html#pyramid.renderers.render

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but I think you need 2 views, one for json and another for the mako one. For the mako view follow [the official docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/narr/templates.html#templating-with-mako-templates) and mmerickel's answer. If you want to have multiple view callables within the same class you can have a look to [pyramid_handlers](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_handlers/).