# How can I let users create html files on the file system from a template?

Tags: python, database, filesystems, pyramid

Right now the home page of my pyramid application has this view callable that lets users add new "pages" to the database. These pages are then viewable on a seperate url.

```
@view_config(route_name='home_page', renderer='templates/edit.pt')
def home_page(request):
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        name= request.params['name']
        body = request.params['body']

        page=Page(name,data)
        new= DBSession.add(page)
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('view_page',pagename=name))

    return {}
```

Instead of this, I want the form submit to create an entirely new html page on the server filesystem. This html page should be in the format of a template I provide with values passed from the home page form at the time it is submitted. Is there a way to do this? I have been looking through http://docs.pylonsproject.org and cannot find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use [`render`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/api/renderers.html#pyramid.renderers.render) to render your template/context to a string

example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6332533/594589) post

```
renderer_dict = {} # dictionary of values to pass to the renderer
new_comment = render('new_comment.pt', renderer_dict, request)
```

Since you have an html template,a nd you want to customize it for your users you should be able to run it through `render` with the correct context and save it to your filesystem.

Comment: that kind of makes sense. How once that new_comment, which I am assuming would be the new html file is rendered, how would I save it to the file system and tell it where to go?

Comment: @BigBoy1337 `new_comment` is a string you can write it to a file using python file api http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html , there are tons of examples on how to use it basically `f = open('/path/to/file/', 'w'); f.write(new_comment); f.close()`

Comment: cool. that makes sense. Where does the request value (that last part of the second line) get defined? Or do I literally just put 'request' there?

Comment: from this: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/renderers.html it seems like just passing in request=request might work