# Get Mako template from within Pyramid app view

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

I'm currently using the Pyramid web framework and I have it configured with Mako templates. I know that I can render a template as a string from within a view method ([Pyramid - Is it possible to render my mako template as a string within my view callable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321625/pyramid-is-it-possible-to-render-my-mako-template-as-a-string-within-my-view-c)), however, I was wondering if it is possible to get the actual template object from within a view and not just a function to render the template.

Looking through the Pyramid source code, in **mako_templating.py** I see that the default TemplateLookup class is overridden with a lookup method for Pyramid. Is there anyway to access this lookup object primarily so I can use the *get_template* function that is part of it?

Thanks for any direction on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This level of introspection is not officially supported by Pyramid's rendering API. That being said, here's a way to do it. This is completely undocumented, unsupported, private, etc, etc. Meaning, don't come complaining when this stops working.

```
from pyramid.mako_templating import IMakoLookup
lookup = request.registry.queryUtility(IMakoLookup, name='mako.')
tmpl = lookup.get_template('myapp:templates/foo.mako')

opts = {} # rendering context
result = tmpl.render_unicode(**opts)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Michael! In the end, I decided to implement a separate Mako Templatelookup instance using the projects configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
from pyramid.renderers import render
sRenderedStuff = render('path/to/template.mak',dContext)
```

An example use case would be something like this:

```
sEmailHtml = render("email/welcome_message_html.mak",dContext)
```

With the following line in your pyramid settings file:

```
mako.directories = your_app:templates
```

The template is fetched from `your_app/templates/email/welcome_message.html`. All `inheritance` and `include` tags work just as they would for templates rendered to a view response.

Comment: Although this works, my question was geared toward using the TemplateLookup instance that's already configured for the application. Calling the `render` function like this does not take into account the existing template configuration.